# Which of the following materials is it most difficult for electrons to flow through?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, material-science

Which of the following materials is it most difficult for electrons to flow through?

A.

glass

B.

aluminum

C.

salt water

Comment: Please avoid homework style questions. If you are confused as to what is considered homework style have a look at the help section

Answer (score 1):

Aluminum is metal and you probably know how electrons flow in metals. Salt water is still water, so you've probably heard that water conducts electricity. All you're left with is glass.